# Function evaluation timed out when dictionary is opened at debug time

Tags: c#, linq

```
foreach (var distinctPart in distinctParts)
{
    var list = partlist.Where(part =>
    {
        if (part.PartNumber.Equals(distinctPart))
            return true;
        return false;
    }).Select(part =>
    {
        return part.Number;
    }).Distinct();
    int quantity = list.Count();
    hwList[distinctPart] = quantity;
}
```

When I'm debugging and open the `hwList` dictionary, I get the error message:

> Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to re enable function evaluation.

Comment: check out this (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/728b9404-60b1-4951-99f8-70a5f75cba61/function-evaluation-disabled-because-a-previous-function-evaluation-timed-out-you-must-continue?forum=vsdebug)

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

Perhaps you can already solve the problem by simplifying this code, like so:

```
foreach (var distinctPart in distinctParts)
{
    var count = partlist.Where(part => part.PartNumber.Equals(distinctPart))                
                       .Select(part => part.Number)
                       .Distinct().Count();
    hwList[distinctPart] = count;
}
```

BTW, do you have a property called `PartNumber` and another `Number`, both defined on a `Part`?